# Is there a hotkey to leave place building mode?

Tags: factorio

In Factorio after you create a structure you can place it from your inventory into the world. But if you have more than one and you only want to place one then you have to go back to the regular cursor.

Currently I do this by clicking on one of the free slots on the bottom panel, or by going back into my inventory, but this is really inconvenient. Is there a hotkey to get back to the regular cursor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While starting the game for the first time, I saw this option in the help.[image: Screenshot of the tip/trick]

Comment: Note that the same key will also switch your  equipped gun, if you have more than one.

Answer (score 4):

Found it, pressing the  <kbd>q</kbd> key will put the item back in the bottom toolbar.

Comment: I assume back to the place it originated from (the 'hand' icon)?

Comment: @Mathias711 correct